# Difference between "überhaupt nicht" and "gar nicht"?

Tags: negation

What is the difference between the expressions "überhaupt (nicht)" and "gar (nicht)"?

Are they used in different contexts? Is the one stronger than the other? Can they be used together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of the expressions convey almost same meaning. However, if you ask which one is stronger than the other one, I would say *überhaupt nicht*.

There is also *überhaupt gar nicht* if you want to give more emphasis.

Comment: Also emphasizing: _»ganz und gar nicht«_

Answer (score 5):

As a standard negation both are exchangeable.

Example:

> Es kommt gar/überhaupt nicht in Frage, dass ich mit dem Zug fahre.
>   (In no case I will travel by train.)

If there is a numeral asked for, as in:

> Wie oft warst du am Kühlschrank?
>   (How often were you at the fridge?)

I would prefer *gar nicht* for the denial, but that is more a matter of taste.